# SwiftUI Computed Property shows "Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior." error

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, computed-properties

I have computed property `timeShown`

I get warning "Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior."

for

```
  if manager.selectedDateByIndex != 0 {
      startIndex = 6
      endIndex = 30
  } else {
      startIndex = hour
      endIndex = 24
  }
```

Full code here

```
var timeIndex: Int
let currentDate = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
@Binding var startIndex: Int
@Binding var endIndex: Int
@EnvironmentObject var manager: BookingManager

var timeShown: String {
        let hourComponent = calendar.dateComponents([.hour], from: currentDate)
        let hour = hourComponent.hour!
        
        if manager.selectedDateByIndex != 0 {
            startIndex = 6
            endIndex = 30
        } else {
            startIndex = hour
            endIndex = 24
        }
        
        if timeIndex < 10 {
            return "0\(timeIndex):00"
        } else if timeIndex > 23 {
            return "0\(timeIndex % 6):00"
        }
        else {
            return "\(timeIndex):00"
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should create a [mre], because you aren't even showing the view code. However, I suspect you are using `timeShown` in the body, therefore you are trying to set `@State` properties in the body too. This creates an infinite loop since setting a `@State` triggers another view update.

Answer (score 1):

The code is mutating the `startIndex` and `endIndex` State as a side-effect of deriving `timeShown`. Which is presumably being used in the View's body and hence will be determined when the system attempts to render the View.

So as the message says, the state that the View depends on to decide what to render is being changed under its feet while it's mid-way through rendering it and that is bad.

There's a far nice explanation of these problems than I can manage over on SwiftUI Lab [here](https://swiftui-lab.com/state-changes/)

To fix the issue here, refactor the code to explicitly listen for whatever implicit state change it is currently expected to listen for. And then when that is detected, set the `startIndex` and `endIndex` in the change handler as needed.

As others have mentioned, there's not really enough code here to work out exactly what is needed, but it would be unsurprising if the solution didn't look something like ...

```
var foo: some View {
    ... displays timeShown somewhere in in here
}
.onChange(of: manager.selectedDateByIndex, perform: { newValue in
    if newValue != 0 {
        startIndex = 6
        endIndex = 30
    } else {
        startIndex = hour
        endIndex = 24
    }
})
```